# Force download image file that's returned as http response using laravel, vue, axios and intervention image

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, intervention

I am trying to set up a media asset database using Laravel, Vue, Axios and Intervention image.
I want the user to be able to set a desired image height and width before downloading an image. This is then sent to the controller using an axios post-request. Inside the controller, intervention image is working its magic(k) and returning my resized file as a response.

Now I want the image that's being returned as a response to trigger a download. What do I need to do with my axios-response?

Here's what I currently have:

**Axios-Request:**

```
resize(file) {
        this.file = file;

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('imageHeight', this.imageHeight);
        formData.append('imageWidth', this.imageWidth);

        axios.post('files/resize/' + file.id, formData).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            this.showNotification(error.response.data.message, false);
            this.fetchFile(this.activeTab, this.pagination.current_page);
        });
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function resize($id, Request $request)
{
    $file = File::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();

    $originalImage = $file->getName($file->type, $file->name, $file->extension);
    $originalImagePath = Storage::get($originalImage);

    $imageHeight = $request['imageHeight'];
    $imageWidth = $request['imageWidth'];

    if ($img = Image::make($originalImagePath)) {
        return $img->resize($imageWidth,$imageHeight)->response();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the `Content-Disposition` response header to be `attachment` rather than `inline`.

http://image.intervention.io/use/http

Comment: Thanks. I still couldn't get it to work because apparently for security reasons JavaScript cannot trigger downloads.